# PHP autoloader does not work in multiple files

Tags: php

In my project I have the following directories (please see the image attached). For the project to work correctly, I have to include my `autoloader.php` file into two files: `index.php` and `classes/FormController.php`

When using my autoloader function that is illustrated below, the autoloader happens to be included only in `index.php`, but not in `classes/FormController.php` as well. I also tried using `__DIR__` but it didn't help.

```
    spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');
    
    function myAutoLoader(string $className)
    {
    
        $path = ['classes/', null];
        $extension = '.php';
    
        foreach($path as $currentDirectory){
    
            $fullPath = $currentDirectory . $className . $extension;
    
            if(!file_exists($fullPath)){
                return false;
            }
    
            include_once $fullPath;

        }
    
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLrOv.png)

Comment: "does not work" is not a good error description. Please extract a [mcve] and clarify what problems exactly you have, what you do, what you observe etc. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Maybe you should use `continue` instead of `return false` in your if clause. Otherwise all subsequent elements in your array won't be tested, when the file was not found in the first path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `return` when it fails to find the class in the first path, so it never tries the second.

Consider something like:

```
    spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');
    
    function myAutoLoader(string $className)
    {
    
        $path = ['classes/', ''];
        $extension = '.php';
    
        $found = false;

        for ($idx = 0; !found && $idx < count($path); $idx++) {

            $fullPath = $path[$idx] . $className . $extension;

            $found = file_exists($fullPath);

            if ($found) {
                include_once $fullPath;
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit to add:

If you're only ever going to be looking in those two directories, a loop is hardly necessary:

```
$fileName = $classname . $extension;

if (file_exists($fileName) {
    include_once $fileName;
} else if (file_exists('classes/' . $fileName) {
    include_once 'classes/' . $filename;
}
```